# Angularjs refreshing select values after adding a new item

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

I am adding a new item to the available select options in a modal box and updating the server. When I close the modal, i want to see the new added option in the select box and actually selecting it without refreshing the entire page, so just select box needs to be updated. Is this possible?

Page;

```
<select ng-model="scores" ng-options="score for score in options.scores" />
```

so on the model box, i add a new value to options.scores

Comment: What's the code for the modal box?

Comment: Are you also updating the model in this scope, that is scores here, or just sent the http request to update the server?

Comment: just sending the http request to update the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `ng-model` in a container object, to prevent any scope hierarchy issues.

```
ng-model="state.scores"
```

Where you defined state like:

```
$scope.state = {};
// then whenever you want to set your scores.
$scope.state.scores = ...
```

You should read up on angular's scope hierarchy. http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html